# Query to display the data from database in a matrix format

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, pivot

My data in Database starts from 1 to 32

```
1
2
3
4
5
-
-
32
```

I need to display the data in 4 columns and 8 rows like

```
1     9     17  25
2     10    18  26
3     11    19  27
4     12    20  28
5     13    21  29
6     14    22  30
7     15    23  31
8     16    24  32
```

I want to display the data from datatable in the above format using sql server 2005.
I don't have any idea about this format to display the in matrix format(4X6).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
declare @numRows int = 8

 ;with cte as (
 select columnA X, row_number() over (order by columnA) rn
  from Table1
 )
 select c1.x A, c2.x B, c3.x C, c4.x D
  from cte c1 
 left join cte c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn-@numRows  
 left join cte c3 on c1.rn = c3.rn-(@numRows * 2)
 left join cte c4 on c1.rn = c4.rn-(@numRows * 3)
 where c1.rn <= @numRows
```

Comment: When I was executing this query I am getting an error Must declare a scalar variable "@numRows".Same query I was using Thanks